# Ho do I implement the property converter for value providers in RAD data Form

Tags: nativescript-angular

I have a RAD data form in my nativescript-angular app. The form has two fields for ID type and ID number. The ID type field is a picker that displays data from a backend service. My source Object looks like:

```
 this.mySourceObj = new User("Passport Id", "A2653JHSJ12");
```

I want my source object to store the value of the ID type as a string.
So I changed the editors using HTML markup, like:

```
 <TKEntityProperty
        tkDataFormProperty
        name="idType"
        displayName="Id Type"
        index="1"
        [valuesProvider]="idTypesProvider"
      >
        <TKPropertyEditor
          tkEntityPropertyEditor
          type="Picker"
        ></TKPropertyEditor>
      </TKEntityProperty>
```

and in my ts file I register my valueproviders like:

```
  this.idTypesProvider = {
            key: "id",
            label: "name",
            items: [...idTypesArr]
        };
```

With this set, my picker editor gets populated with the data but when I select one item, it does not reflect in my code so at the time of form submission the field is null.

I would like to get the value of the selected item as a complete object i.e. (id, name, ...).

I have tried using the property committed event to get the committed value but it is logs an index value of the item.

```
        if (args.propertyName === "idType") {
            const selectedIdType = this.mySourceObj.idType;
            console.log(`the committed id type is :`, selectedIdType);
        } else {
            console.log("No property selected");
        }
```

I have also come across the property convert that is attatched in the dom like:

```
 <TKEntityProperty
        tkDataFormProperty
        name="idType"
        displayName="Id Type"
        index="1"
        [converter]="valsConverter"
        [valuesProvider]="idTypesProvider"
      >
        <TKPropertyEditor
          tkEntityPropertyEditor
          type="Picker"
        ></TKPropertyEditor>
      </TKEntityProperty>
```

But I do not know how to implement the "Converter". Any help is highly appreciated.

I want a situation where when the user selects an ID type, my console can log The complete object of the selected Item.

Comment: Here is the example of converter https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-ui-samples-angular/blob/master/dataform/app/examples/data-services/movie-converter.ts

Comment: cheers man, i had to find a work around to save the day but i will  try this.